# Converting Python Json to dict

Tags: python

I am calling an API which returns a complicated json:

```
{"results": [{"attrs": {"name": "par.abd","state": 1.0},
              "joins": {},
              "meta": {},
              "name": "par.abd",
              "type": Host"
             },
             {"attrs": {"name": "bbc.abd","state": 1.0},
              "joins": {},
              "meta": {},
              "name": "bbc.abd",
              "type": "Host"
             }]}
```

How do I extract just the name and state for attrs?

Comment: What is your input type? A string?

Comment: you can use `import ast; ast.literal_eval(your_string)` to convert string to dict. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary

Comment: @shotgunner The OP said it's JSON and you recommend using `ast` to parse it? Surely you must be joking. That's *clearly* not the right tool for the job.

Comment: Siong: this is JSON, not Python

Comment: @Aran-Fey AFAIK `ast` module use for evaluate string containing python literals.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski JSON is represented as string and dictionary in python. is there any other way to represent JSON in python ?

Comment: If it's JSON, use the `json` module to parse it. Not anything else.

Comment: Shotgunner: read 1st comment here to learn fundamental difference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Use the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module:

```
import json

json_string = """{"results": [{"attrs": {"name": "par.abd","state": 1.0},"joins": {},"meta": {},"name": "par.abd","type": "Host"},{"attrs": {"name": "bbc.abd","state": 1.0},"joins": {},"meta": {},"name": "bbc.abd","type": "Host"} ]}"""
data = json.loads(json_string)

for res in data['results']:
    print(res['attrs']['name'], res['attrs']['state'])


# par.abd 1.0
# bbc.abd 1.0
```

Note that I had to add a missing `"` near the end of your string - I hope it only disappeared when you copied it here.

Answer (score 0):

As @Aran-Fey suggested, you should use the [json](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html) module, which turns the JSON string into Python dicts and lists.

```
import json

json_string = '{"results": [{"attrs": {"name": "par.abd","state": 1.0},"joins": {},"meta": {},"name": "par.abd","type": "Host"},{"attrs": {"name": "bbc.abd","state": 1.0},"joins": {},"meta": {},"name": "bbc.abd","type": "Host"} ]}'
data = json.loads(json_string)
for item in data['results']:
    attrs = item['attrs']
    print(attrs['name'], attrs['state'])
```

Btw, there's a syntax error in your JSON example. A double quote is missing before the first occurrence of 'Host'.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same answer as Thierry.
Same issue with the json being invalid.

```
import json
text = '''{
    "results": [
        {
            "attrs": {
                "name": "par.abd",
                "state": 1.0
            },
            "joins": {
            },
            "meta": {
            },
            "name": "par.abd",
            "type": "Host"
        },
        {
            "attrs": {
                "name": "bbc.abd",
                "state": 1.0
            },
            "joins": {
            },
            "meta": {
            },
            "name": "bbc.abd",
            "type": "Host"
        }
    ]
}
'''
payload = json.loads(text)
results = payload['results']
for result in results:
    attrs = result['attrs']
    name = attrs['name']
    state = attrs['state']
    print("name: %s state: %s"%(name,state))
```